# Help identify NG boiler popping sound

Tags: hvac, heating, boiler

Help me identify cause of popping sounds coming from a hydronic natural gas boiler (for home heating, NOT a water heater): 2 or 3 pops occur after burners light up, within 10-15 seconds, never at any other times. The pops can be heard only in the vicinity of the boiler (basement), not elsewhere in the house, except if I press an ear to the radiators. The pops started last winter, and coincide with changing circulators. Previously had Armstrong S25 (just like the B&G): 1750 RPM, 1/12HP, replaced with Taco 007 with integral flow check: 3250 RPM, 1/25HP.

ABOUT the BOILER: Raypak 134WT, installed in late 1980s (133,000 BTU input / 106,000 BTU output), single stage. Boiler has been and is working flawlessly otherwise. Boiler is clean, flames are blue. Chimney vented. Pressure: 12.

15 second video, pop starts around 10 seconds:

[Popping boiler sound video on dailymotion:](https://dai.ly/x8d082w)

Answer (score 1):

The Taco has a maximum flow of 23 GPM at zero head, while the Armstrong was 31 GPM, so it's possible that the Taco is not moving heat out of the boiler at the same rate as the Armstrong at its ~25% lower flow. That may allow some internal part of the boiler to expand due to heating more quickly than before. If that's the case, the popping may be nothing more than the sound of some piece of metal moving past another and creating a "slip-stick" noise.

You can do an experiment to prove or disprove this theory. Start up the boiler, wait for the pop, let it run another minute or so, then stop the boiler. Now start it up again. Does it pop this time? If not, the quicker expansion theory is supported; the metal is already warm and expanded, so it doesn't pop again.

If you have the time, the inclination and the DIY gene, you may be able to find the part that is making the noise by using a stethoscope or a length of 1/2" PVC pipe held to your ear while touching various boiler parts. If you find two parts that are rubbing together to make the pop, a little silicone grease between them will stop the noise.

Although this noise is probably causing no harm, a better choice would have been the Taco 0010, which has performance closer to the original equipment. See the chart below. Click to expand. (Photo credit: Taco)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I knew Taco 0010 circ was a better replacement, but was not available in an emergency, hence 007. I will try your suggestion as well as put in a Taco 0010. Will post results in case others are curious. Thanks again.